# How do they do it? Dialogs over home screen

Tags: android, text, dialog, android-widget

I'm writing an Android application and I would like to place a dialog or view over the home screen so that a user can enter text without jumping into my full application. I can't seem to get this to work. If I present a dialog (even in a transparent activity), my application launches.

If you don't know what I'm talking about, take a look at the Facebook widget. I want to replicate a similar behavior to the clicking on the "What's on your mind?" box.

Thanks for any help in advance!

-Brian

Comment: "If I present a dialog (even in a transparent activity), my application launches." What does this mean to you? To me, an "application" is going to *have* to launch, otherwise your code will not run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My problem was that the application always launched to display the dialog.

To solve this, I set the activity lauch mode to `singleInstance` in the manifest. Now it shows the dialog over the home screen!

Comment: Altought it's working, it's makes bug in andoid 6, (yes, I saw it's an aold question, but google doent care...). You have to use 'documentLaunchMode' to prevent it to overide your own application in the "Recent Screens" (especially if you also use excludeFromRecents).

Answer (score 7):

They *are* launching an activity, but they've set the activity's theme so it looks like a Dialog.

In your manifest, you have to add something like this under the `<activity>` tag: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I start an activity from my app widget? I can't seem to figure out pending intents. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot, I tried with Theme.Dialog

```
  <activity android:name=".language"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

But in my code, there is 2 different floating windows : my layout and the tile. Here is the following code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Dialog; 

public class language extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this); 
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        dialog.setTitle("Raygional"); 
        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

PS : I know this should be a question rather than an answer

Comment: then why did you post it as an answer?

Comment: It may interest others who want to do a Dialog over homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

Use Service for that

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

below is some code`

```
public class HomepopupDataService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "HomepopupDataService";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

    CountDownTimer dlgCountDown;
    Log.e("---------------", "onHandleIntent");
    dlgCountDown = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.e("---------------", "onHandleIntent++");
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    DialogActivity.class);

            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    }.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
}

}
```