# Android menu for widget

Tags: android, menu, android-widget

I need create menu for widget like this https://www.gstatic.com/android/market/com.bugabuga.switcher/ss-320-0-0. What components are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is a activity styled as a dialog.

This thread will answer your question: [How do they do it? Dialogs over home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705162/how-do-they-do-it-dialogs-over-home-screen)